# showing a php page in central part of the website

Tags: javascript, php, html

with this web page:

https://jsfiddle.net/99b92jy1/12/

i have "This is my TEXT" in the white part of the page with this:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var bodyText=["This is my TEXT"]
        function generateText(sentenceCount){
            for (var i=0; i<sentenceCount; i++)
            document.write(bodyText)
        }
    </script>
```

i have an item in left menu "To Hello.php"

i have a php file named hello.php with this code:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello ";
?>
```

i need to show hello.php file result in place of the text "This is my TEXT". Need to load in this place the correspondent .php file when user clicks on the menu items.

i have tryed to replace "This is my TEXT" with all content of the php file but doesn't work.

What i need to do for show a php page in this area?

Comment: please create a working example of your current problem so that we can check and come to what's going on? As well as describe your problem correctly.

Comment: You could look into using something like AJAX and displaying the results in a DIV area. This would mean you create multiple PHP files, use an AJAX call to the desired result and load in a specified DIV

Comment: i have updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cargarDiv(div,url){
            $(div).load(url);
        }
    </script>
```

replacing main with this:

```
<main>
    <div id="central" class="innertube">                
        <h1>foo text</h1>                               
    </div>
</main>
```

and using a href in the menu item like this :

```
<a href="javascript:cargarDiv('#central','hello.php');">hello</a>
```